# Determine whether $xy''-(\cos x)y' + (\sin x)y =0$ is exact?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine whether $xy''-(\cos x)y' + (\sin x)y =0$ is exact when $x>0$.

I have done these kinds of problems where you have $M(x,y)$ and $N(x,y)$. You take the derivative and if they are the same then the equation is exact and we can solve it. However, I do not know how to solve this equation. In this equation, it has a second derivative. How would I solve this?

Comment: LHS=$y''x+y'-y'(1+\cos x)+y\sin x=(...)'$

Comment: can we say?
$$ -y' + \frac{d}{dx}(y \ sinx\ \ +xy')=0$$ 
$$ \frac{d}{dx}(y \ sinx\ \ +xy')=y'$$

Comment: Maple find this solution $$y \left( x \right) = \left( {\it \_C1}\,\int \!{\frac {1}{{x}^{2}{
{\rm e}^{{\it Ci} \left( x \right) }}}}\,{\rm d}x+{\it \_C2} \right) x
{{\rm e}^{{\it Ci} \left( x \right) }}
$$

Comment: My attempt was from $xy''=(ycosx)'$ using integration by parts and TFC find that the criterion for exactness reads as $C'(y)=-2-\cos x$, where $xy'-y=y\cos x+C(y)$. When we derive in previous equation using this criterion we obtain from  $y'+xy''-y'=y'\cos x-y\sin x+C'(y)\cdot y'$, this is $xy''+2y'+y\sin x=0$, thus this is your new problem, for $x>0$. There are some methods for find solutions, it is necessary to know previously a solution to implement some of these methods. I don't know if this problem appear as second part of your problem. I hope that my computations are right.

Answer (score 0):

in the case of second order linear differential equations, this "exactness" is defined differently and I'm not sure if it has any relation to what you mentioned.

it's defined like this :

> For an equation $$a(x)y'' + b(x)y' + c(x)y = 0$$
> if $$a''(x) - b'(x) + c(x) = 0$$ we say it's exact,
> which in the case of your question it is.

‌

so how do you solve exact second order equations ?

exact second order equations reduce to this first order equation :

$$a(x)y' + [b(x) - a'(x)]y = C$$  (note: $C$ is just a constant, don't mistake it with c(x) )

solve the above linear first-order equation and the answer $y(x)$ is what you're looking for

This whole "exact second order equation" thing seems impractical, I usually find this types of problems complicated

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).